# .NET MVC - where to use dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm currently injecting dependencies into controllers using a IoC container (Castle). This is possible because you need to create a custom controller factory which enables the dependency injection.

What are other examples of dependency injection? At which point in an MVC application would you use it, and where does a 'factory' come into play?

Comment: If you use Castle, I would suggest that http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/, personally, I feel it's a very good example to follow regarding how to use IOC

Comment: I'm looking at Sutekishop but cannot download the latest source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Ninject. At my project:

- Service layer objects are injected into controllers (using constructor).
- Repositories are injected into service layer objects (using constructor).
- ObjectContext is injected into repositories (using constructor).
- web.config setting are encapsulated into a class, which implements IAppSettings interface, which is then injected into service layer.
- NinjectActionInvoker is injected as IActionInvoker. It takes care of injecting services into ActionFilters.
- I have my own implementation of `IPrincipal` interface, which is injected into service layer, instead of referring to `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Example using Ninject:

```
public class UserService : GenericService<User>, IUserService
{
    public ISettingService SettingService { get; set; }
    public ICTEmailSender CTEmailSender { get; set; }
    public ICTSettings CTSettings { get; set; }
    public ICTPrincipal User { get; set; }
}
```

Ninject rules:

```
Bind<ICTPrincipal>().ToMethod(c => (ICTPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User).OnlyIf(a => HttpContext.Current.User is ICTPrincipal);
Bind<ICTEmailSender>().To<CTEmailSender>();
Bind<ICTSettings>().To<CTSettings>();
```

Not only service is injected into controller, but parts of service are injected into it. It makes service more testable. I am sure it can be easily ported into Castle.

Comment: In other words: Dependency Injection all the way ;-)

Comment: Pretty interesting, any example that we can follow

Comment: Yes this should port easily. I was a bit off track focusing on a `factory` that needed to be applied, however this is not the case. You can also inject methods and other objects without a factory.

Comment: Is it typical for different components (like: Controllers, Services, Repositories) to be 'installed' using separate configurations (e.g. `IWindsorInstaller` in Windsor)? I'm deducting from documentation that this is indeed the case. However it's also allowing for only one 'binding' per dependency. What if two components depend on the same object, where (in which installer) would you `configure` or `install` this binding?

Comment: @Ropstah: I am not an expert in Windsor, but from what I see in documentation, you should have it in `installer` related to this object's class. If this object is `Repository`, you should place it in `RepositoryInstaller`.

Comment: I understand, but what if both `Repository` and `Service` depend on `User`. I cannot define `Bind<User>` in `RepositoryInstaller` **and** `ServiceInstaller`

Comment: Or is this bad **layering** if repositories and services _both_ rely on user?

Comment: If you want to inject User, you should probably have `UserInstaller` or `EntityInstaller`, but I want to repeat, that I am not Windsor expert here:)

Comment: If I want to inject something to `Controllers` I need to have a `ControllerInstaller`, if I want to inject something to `Services` I think I need a `ServiceInstaller`. However it's not about where to inject **to** but about **what** is being injected.... Why don't I just get it?!?!

Comment: @Ropstah: http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-three-writing-your-first-installer.ashx http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx If you need to inject `Service` to other class, you need `Service` installer.

Comment: I was referring to the same information actually... You also need to define `implementation` (Windsor) or `binding` (Ninject) for components which are placed in constructors. Can both `ControllerInstaller` and `ServiceInstaller` have a `binding` for e.g. `IUser` dependency?

Comment: @Ropstah: Won't Windsor resolve constructor injection basing on other installers?

Comment: I guess it does, but which component installer should _contain_ the implementation definition?

Comment: @Ropstah: As I said earlier, you should probably place it in separate, dedicated installer (`UserInstaller` or `EntityInstaller`).

Comment: So this means that I need installers for both `components` as well as `implementations` ?